# No sube la tabla al datagridview y me de un warning de invalid operation exception

Tags: c#, mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema. Intento subir una tabla al datagridview, pero al intentarlo, me da un warning con el mensaje `invalid operation exception`.

Dejo los detalles de excepción dada.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=No row can be added to a DataGridView control that does not have columns. Columns must be added first.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.AddInternal(Boolean newRow, Object[] values)
       at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)
       at Proyecto_final1.Worktable.llenar1() in D:\Manejador de items\Proyecto final1\Proyecto final1\Worktable.cs:line 88
       at Proyecto_final1.Worktable.Worktable_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Manejador de items\Proyecto final1\Proyecto final1\Worktable.cs:line 35
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

Y este es la linea que VS 2015 me señala, la tabla tiene 8 columnas

```
 conx.Open(); MySqlDataReader leer;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from usuario", conx);
            leer = cmd.ExecuteReader(); dgvUsuario.Rows.Clear();
            while (leer.Read())
            {
                this.dgvUsuario.Rows.Add(leer.GetValue(0), leer.GetValue(1), leer.GetValue(2), leer.GetValue(3), leer.GetValue(4), leer.GetValue(5), leer.GetValue(6), leer.GetValue(7));
            }
            conx.Close();
```

Alguna idea colegas?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias implementar algo como esto

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from usuario", conx);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dgvUsuario.DataSource = dt;
```

de esta forma las columnas se crearan de forma automatica segun los datos del datatable

Si quieres usar el Rows.Add() primeramente deberias crear las columnas

```
dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 8;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "NombreCol1";
dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "NombreCol2";
```

[DataGridView.Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: muchas gracias tenia problemas con esto, ya que fue lo que me mi maestro nos mostro pense que hacia algo mal, pero me pregunto a que se debe mi problema, acaso es algo de versiones de plataformas? de nuevo gracias funciono perfectamente

Comment: si creas las columnas usando el Rows.Add() tienes que previamente crear las columnas usando el dgvUsuario.Columns.Add()

Comment: oh y como deberia proceder en ese caso?

Comment: edite la pregunta, agregue el codigo para crear las columnas con codigo antes de agregar las rows